# Save just class base from derived class in Entity

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity, dbcontext

I´m trying save in entity context just the base class from a derived class instance, but i get error "Invalid column name xxx" because my table/class base doesnt have the derived field, and it´s correct. There is a table/class to represent derived it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        EntidadeFuncionario func = new EntidadeFuncionario();
        func.TipoPessoa = "F";
        func.Nome = "A";
        func.DataAdmissao = DateTime.Now;
        BLLFuncionario bllFunc = new BLLFuncionario();
        if (bllFunc.Salvar(func))
            Console.Write("Sucesso!");
        else
            Console.Write("Falha");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public abstract class EntidadePessoa
{

    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome{get;set;}
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public string TipoPessoa { get; set; }

}

public class EntidadeFuncionario : EntidadePessoa
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataAdmissao { get; set; }


}

 public class BLLFuncionario : BLLPessoaBase
{
    public override bool Salvar(EntidadePessoa func)
    {
        if (base.Salvar((EntidadePessoa)func))
        {                
            if (((EntidadeFuncionario)func).DataAdmissao != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("func salvo");
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public abstract class BLLPessoaBase
{
    ContextWN context = new ContextWN();

    public virtual bool Salvar(EntidadePessoa pessoa)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pessoa.Nome))
        {
            context.Pessoas.Add(pessoa);
            context.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("Pessoa salva");               
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
}

public class ContextWN : DbContext
{
    public ContextWN()
        : base("WNEntities")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<EntidadePessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntidadePessoa>().ToTable("TB_PESSOA");

    }
}
```

> I have table TB_PESSOA (Id, Nome, DataNascimento, TipoPessoa) and TB_FUNCIONARIO (Id, DataAdmissao, IdPessoa[FK])
>
> there is an propertie (DataAdmissao) in object EntidadeFuncionario/Employee. I get this object in my BLLPessoaBase class like a cast. So far, ok, but when i try save ONLY Person (i dont wanna save EntidadeFuncionario/Employee, for now) in my context (my context doesnt have EntidadeFuncionario dbset, because it will stay in separate DLL), c# throw a exception "Invalid column DataAdmissao" because this propert is in object Employee, even if this object Employee be a cast EntidadeFuncionario/Employee
>
> My idea is keep Pessoa/Person module in a separate DLL and be able to re
>   utility and various projects, like a Funcionario/Employee module example. Funcionario/Employee module would have your specific "save" after save "Pessoa/Person". I dont know if its a good practice but i thought this way

Comment: EF Entities are partial classes so don't derive to add a field, just expand the entity class and add the field there. Then override `SaveChanges` method of your Context to ignore that property

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to add more properties for an entity model, you should use partial class and [**NotMapped**] attribute for those columns that did not exist in your table.

*For example:*

```
public partial class Person
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get;set;}
    public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
}
public partial class Person
{
    [NotMapped]
    public string ExtendProperties { get;set;}
}
```

In your case, if you want to reuse the entity model for various modules.I suggested this way:

> **Person module:**

```
public partial class Person
{ 
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Nome { get;set;}
     public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
     HasKey(x => x.Id);
     ToTable("dbo.TB_PESSOA");     
}
```

How to add the mapping configuration

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMapping());
}
```

> **Employee module**

```
public partial class Employee : Person
{   
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; } 
}
public class EmployeeMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
     HasKey(x => x.Id);
     ToTable("dbo.TB_EMPLOYEE");     
}
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMapping());
}
```

Now you can reuse your entity model for various modules.

Comment: In fact, i don´t wanna expand Person class e that´s not happen in my code, but there is an propertie (DataAdmissao) in object EntidadeFuncionario/Employee. I get this object in my BLLPessoaBase class like a cast. So far, ok, but when i try save ONLY Person (i dont wanna save EntidadeFuncionario/Employee, for now) in my context (my context doesnt have EntidadeFuncionario dbset, because it will stay in separate DLL), c# throw a exception "Invalid column DataAdmissao" because this propert is in object Employee, even if this object Employee be a cast EntidadeFuncionario/Employee